# Homology of $S^1$ with local coefficients

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology

I'm trying to compute the cellular chain complex $C_{*}(\tilde{S^1})$ where $\tilde{S^1}$ is the universal cover of $S^1$, as a $\mathbb{Z}[t, t^{-1}]$ module.  This can then be used to compute the homology of $S^1$ with local coefficients in $A$,  $ H_{k}(S^1; A_{\rho})$ for any abelian group $A$ and any homomorphism $\rho: \pi_{1}S^1 \to Aut_{\mathbb{Z}}(A).$  This is an exercise in Davis and Kirk's "Lecture notes in Algebraic Topology".

I know that the chain complex will be $\mathbb{Z}[t, t^{-1}]$  in the zeroth and first degree.  I am having trouble computing the boundary map, however.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Instead of the definition, try to compute zero dimensional cohomology first using coinvariants of a group action, see Brown's cohomology of groups. Then try to use Poincare duality.